# How to find some value in model find

Tags: yii2

```
 $graph_name = T_Graph_Name::find()->all();

 $g1_01_short_desc = $graph_name::find()->where(['g_code'=>'g1_01']);
```

thx for help.

Answer (score 2):

find()->all() return all models of you model (T_Graph_Name)

if you want just some models (eg: filtering the column g_code = 'g1_01') you should use

```
$models =   T_Graph_Name::find()->->where(['g_code'=>'g1_01'])->all();
```

or

```
$model = T_Graph_Name::find()->->where(['g_code'=>'g1_01'])->one();
```

all() return a collection of models  so for accessing a column you should use an index  or iterate over eg:

```
 foreach($models as $m ){
    echo $m->your_column_name;
 }
```

one() retunr just one model so for accessi a column you con use

```
echo $model->your_column_name;
```

Comment: i have data in T_Graph_Name about 2000 records. if i find 2000 time will be make my server to slow or not ?

Comment: why you want find 2000 times  ? ..  if you need  a set of row the you can filter using where ...the first sample  `T_Graph_Name::find()->->where(['g_code'=>'g1_01'])->all();`  return only the rows  that satisfy the condition in where()